# UserWarning in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arr = np.random.randint(1,50,10)
print(arr)
y, x = np.histogram(arr,bins=np.arange(51))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x[:-1],y)
fig.show()
```

The error displayed is:

`<ipython-input-4-31fe4acba862>:8: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using  module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.`

Although I still get a graph:
[image: Graph I get..]

Comment: If you're using Jupyter notebook: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18047

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning comes from `fig.show()`. You can remove this when using jupyter.